# Converting vertical Table to Horizontal table

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

I am looking for a clean, fast and nice solution for this operation.
First I have a table that looks like this

```
field_id   -    item_id   -   value
   1        -     781  -       name1
   2        -     781   -      lastname1
   3        -     781   -      phone1
   1        -     782   -      name2
   2        -     782   -      lastname2
   3        -     782   -      phone2
   1        -     783   -      name3
   2        -     783   -      lastname3
   3        -     783   -      phone3
```

I want to display this table like this:

```
item_id    -    name   -   lastname   -   phone
781     -        name1    -  lastname1   -   phone1
782     -        name2    -  lastname2   -   phone2   
783     -        name3    -  lastname3   -   phone3
```

I tried this

```
SELECT field_id, item_id,
(CASE WHEN field_id = 1 THEN value END) AS name,
(CASE WHEN field_id = 2 THEN value END) AS lastname,
(CASE WHEN field_id = 3 THEN value END) AS phone
FROM cq6xb_fields_values
GROUP BY item_id;
```

But I get this strange  result

```
item_id    -    name   -   lastname   -   null 
781     -        null -  lastname1   -   null 
782     -        null -  lastname2   -   null 
783     -        null -  lastname3   -   null
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes ttally sense. You are trying to group and not to group within one query at the same time, you cannot have it both ways. If a field is not in the GROUP BY you can only use it within the SELECT with an aggragate function like MIN(), MAX(), SUM() etc. So you cannot use field_id, since you get random results. It doesn't know from which of the three records it should choose the field_id.

Comment: And anyway, it will use the same value for field_id in each of your CASE statements, and you want three different values. Can't have multiple values for one column within a select, my friend. SO MySQL in your case chooses at random the value 2 for each item_id, could have been 1 or 3 too, than the other columns would have been NULL.

Comment: By the way that table structure is BAD. But that may not be your fault, I realize this. But if you can, just make a table with fields item_id, name, lastname, and phone and throw this one away. On a brighter note: see my answer.

Comment: Or see P. Salmon’s

Comment: Thanks, I searched a ton of different methods but none worked quite nicely as P.Salmo's. I was afraid of making a noob question but you guys are awesome, this is the first time i ask a question here and I am really glad I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't far away just add max and you can remove field id since you are not using it.

```
SELECT item_id,
max(CASE WHEN field_id = 1 THEN value END) AS name,
max(CASE WHEN field_id = 2 THEN value END) AS lastname,
max(CASE WHEN field_id = 3 THEN value END) AS phone
FROM cq6xb_fields_values
GROUP BY item_id;

+---------+-------+-----------+--------+
| item_id | name  | lastname  | phone  |
+---------+-------+-----------+--------+
|     781 | name1 | lastname1 | phone1 |
|     782 | name2 | lastname2 | phone2 |
|     783 | name3 | lastname3 | phone3 |
+---------+-------+-----------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Easy and nice! Simpler than mine. I hope, though, that the OP understands why this works and his not. And I still think he should just alter his table structure if at all possible.

Comment: @roemer This is known as conditional aggregation and there are lots of examples in SO.

Comment: I had not come upon it on SO yet I have used similar constructs myself in the past, but for other causes. Thank you for responding and naming it for me, now this will stick to memory even better.

Comment: Thanks, It worked perfecty, I am new to MySQL and what I am trying to achieve is merge some joomla custom fields into a more friendly/readable interface. This solution is also very fast to execute unlike some Join I tried that took to long.

Comment: The joins were probably show because the join fields were not indexed, just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: see my comments under your question, the table structure is inherently bad, that is why this gets so complicated.

If you really want it this way, you need either to join to the tables restricted to the belonging field_id value, or work with subqueries.

So this could work:

```
SELECT main.item_id, names.value AS name, lastnames.value AS lastname, phones.value AS phone
FROM cq6xb_fields_values AS main
    LEFT JOIN cq6xb_fields_values AS names ON names.item_id = main.item_id AND names.field_id=1
    LEFT JOIN cq6xb_fields_values AS lastnames ON lastnames.item_id = main.item_id AND lastnames.field_id=2
    LEFT JOIN cq6xb_fields_values AS phones ON phones.item_id = main.item_id AND phones.field_id=3
GROUP BY main.item_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like this before, but it was slow since the number of fields are a lot more, the structure is the native custom fields joomla uses so I cant change that.